# Magento 1.5: Where to enter Default Meta Description?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, seo, magento-1.5

Where do I set the **Default** Meta Description and Keywords in the Backend of Magento 1.5?
I know how to set this individually to product-pages, categories etc., but where do I have to enter the default fallback?

it seems that in older versions this could be done under system --> general --> Design --> HTML head, but in Magento 1.5 I miss this section.

Comment: It should be there.  Try changing your `Current Configuration Scope` while on that screen

Comment: i did, but it doesnt appear. Could you verify this with Magento Version 1.5?  I just had a look at another project with Magento Version 1.6 - and there the HTML Head Section is available

Comment: I'm running several versions but I don't have 1.5 installed.  I'm going to install it today and check it out.  In the meantime I found this MagentoCommerce.com post that appears to be relevant to your problem:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/271473/

Comment: SOLUTION! :
if you use a local code folder - simply copy app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml to app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml

... the right hint was found here: [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/77960/P15/) Thank you @seanbreeden for mindsharing!

Comment: Cool! You should post it as an answer just in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: yeah! will do this in about 8 hours ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it! if you use a local code folder - simply copy 
*app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml* 
to *app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml* 
and the HTML Head Section will "re-appear".

The right hint was found here: [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/77960/P15/)

Thank you @seanbreeden for mindsharing!